# Button.onClick.AddListener() not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been struggling with this for the last couple of hours.
I can access and edit the properties of the button, but the onClick.AddListener() function does not work. Here is my code:

```
GameObject gameObject;
        gameObject = Resources.Load("Prefabs/MenuOption") as GameObject;

        gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(option.imgPath);

        Button button = gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();

        // Testing to see if I can change button properties (works)
        ColorBlock colorss = button.colors;
        colorss.highlightedColor = Color.magenta;
        button.colors = colorss;
        
        // This does not work
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => Test(button));
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => { Debug.Log("click"); });

        Instantiate(gameObject, pos, new Quaternion(), GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);
```

And here is an instance of the prefab:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjzB3.png)

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I think subscribing to onClick event on the instantiated game object (not on the game object you use to instantiate another object) should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! It was such a simple thing but I just started in unity so I didn't know what was wrong.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to `onClick` event on the instantiated game object (not on the game object you use to instantiate another object) should solve your problem.